# Keep last two elements wrapping together

Tags: css

I have a dynamically generated UL/LI list with a variable number of elements in it, displayed horizontally. I want to set up my CSS so that if wrapping is needed, the last two elements in the list always wrap together.

Markup:

```
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
...
</ul>
```

Output

```
Displays in one line when there's enough space: 
A B C D E F G

Breaks like this first when shorter:
A B C D E
F G

This is fine, too:
A B C D
E F G

NEVER THIS:
A B C D E F
G
```

The space the list uses is responsive and the elements are dynamic, so nothing fixed-width will help. I don't have control of the markup because it comes from a CMS. My list items are currently floated, but changing to flex or inline-block is fine.

Is this possible in pure CSS?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what your markup for the list would look like? How are you generating it?

Comment: You can definitely do this with JS, e.g.: `<p class="nobreak">A B C D E F G</p>`, then `$('p.nobreak').each(function() {$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\s+(\S+)$/, '&nbsp;$1'))})`

Comment: I thought I was clear, but sure: It's just <ul><li>A</li><li>B</li>...</ul> and is generated from a CMS.

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved using CSS given the markup that you are using.

Comment: i think what css don't will help for your issue, use JS and calculate the width of all objects ((

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible in CSS.

1. Set the `ul`'s min-width equal to the space needed for the last two elements.
2. Set the margin-right of the next-to-last `li` equal to the width of the last `li`.
3. Set the margin-left of the last `li` equal to the negative of its width.

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rvLdu54x/)

**CSS**:

```
ul {
  min-width: 4em;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 2em;
}

li:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  margin-right: 2em;
}

li:nth-last-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: -2em;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow the last item's width to be dynamic... but I am extremely impressed! If nobody can figure that out (and I'm honestly not sure it's possible) then I'm going to accept this.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your "no fixed-width" criteria.  I don't think it's possible in CSS without knowing the widths of the last two elements, but that can be gotten fairly easily with JavaScript.

Comment: I'm accepting this because I think it's as close as CSS can possibly get, but it's worth adding another comment because it doesn't 100% answer the question. This solution works great, even dynamically, as long as you can control the maximum width of the last element. The only real penalties for over-estimating the last element's width is that it breaks earlier than expected, ad makes right-aligning the entire list undesirable. The width of the second-to-last element need not be known if you control the list's minimum width otherwise. (I'm using a media query for that.) Thanks again for this.

Comment: Great! In case it helps someone: the one-but-last item takes extra space on the right  so that the last item can appear next to it. The last item moves itself to the left to fill the space created by the one-but-last item.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex-wrap property, it will adjust spacing automatically.

```
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will meet the OP's requirement that the last two items wrap together.